# Froala Editor, How count the row?

Tags: count, editor, row, page-numbering, froala

there is a way to count the rows to define a page number?
somebody has added a page number in this editor?

i use this for capture the event but i don't know how cout the row

$('#edit').on('editable.contentChanged', function (e, editor {}

Answer (score 0):

i found a this mode but i don't know if is correct

TAKE A TEXT
 $('#edit').editable('getHTML', false, true)

COUNT a

TAG for understand how many row
var n = $("p").length;